# How to include a scene in SceneBuilder only for some versions of macOS?

Tags: swift, swiftui

My problem is the following: I have an application that uses the `MenuBarExtra()` scene type, which was introduced in macOS 13. But I want to have a version of the app for macOS 12, too, just without that scene.

I've looked into all sorts of permuations using `@available` and `if #available` but haven't been able to come up with something that compiles.

In principle, this is what I would like:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @ObservedObject public var userSettings: UserSettings
    @ObservedObject public var viewModel: ViewModel
    /* more variables and initializer declarations */  

   var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup("Pipelines") {
            PipelineListView(model: viewModel, settings: userSettings)
        }
        .commands {
            AppCommands()
        }
        Settings {
            SettingsView(settings: userSettings)
        }
        if #available(macOS 13.0, *) {
            MenuBarExtra() {
                MenuBarExtraContent(model: viewModel)
            } label: {
                MenuBarExtraLabel(model: viewModel)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code doesn't compile, though. The compiler complains that "Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result builder 'SceneBuilder'".

Any ideas what I could try?

Comment: And to clarify: I am aware of the older `NSStatusItem` API, but I want to use the new API for macOS 13 and nothing for macOS 12. The reason for all of this is that it's okay for the app to require macOS 13, but I want to be able to run the unit tests on macOS 12, because Github Actions doesn't have a runner for macOS 13 yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SceneBuilder` doesn't allow conditionals, and there's no `AnyScene` type eraser, so you can't have a single `MyApp` type that returns a different `Scene` definition depending on the macOS version.

Instead, create **two** types conforming to `App`: one for macOS 13 and later, and one for older systems. Do not attach the `@main` annotation to either type. Factor out the common stuff to a third type that conforms to `Scene`.

Here's the common `Scene`:

```
struct CommonScene: Scene {
    @ObservedObject var userSettings: UserSettings
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

   var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup("Pipelines") {
            PipelineListView(model: viewModel, settings: userSettings)
        }
        .commands {
            AppCommands()
        }
        Settings {
            SettingsView(settings: userSettings)
        }
    }
}
```

The `App` for old systems just wraps `CommonScene`:

```
struct OldSystemApp: App {
    @StateObject var userSettings = UserSettings()
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some Scene {
        CommonScene(
            userSettings: userSettings,
            viewModel: viewModel
        )
    }
}
```

The `App` for macOS 13 adds the `MenuBarExtra`:

```
struct App13: App {
    @StateObject var userSettings = UserSettings()
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        CommonScene(
            userSettings: userSettings,
            viewModel: viewModel
        )
        
        MenuBarExtra() {
            MenuBarExtraContent(model: viewModel)
        } label: {
            MenuBarExtraLabel(model: viewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, write your own little type with a `static func main()` that runs the appropriate `App` type's `main` depending on whether macOS 13 is available, and add `@main` to that type:

```
@main
struct MyMain {
    static func main() {
        if #available(macOS 13.0, *) {
            App13.main()
        } else {
            OldSystemApp.main()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! And for my purposes I don't even have to extract a common scene. I can leave everything in `App13` and have a practically empty scene in `OldSystemApp`.  If you're interested you can see the actual implementation here: https://github.com/erikdoe/ccmenu2/blob/98cc8cde4391696d559df1098f2f7d1a34db4c19/CCMenu/Source/App/CCMenuApp.swift

Comment: And one small correction: it should be `static func main()`. It's hard to get over  `void main()` after years and years of C, right?